# Retrieving value from Datepicker to notifications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

My App is on Windows phone 8.1 , It is like a reminder ,For that i need to retrieve the date and time that the user sets , and to make a notification at that specified time and date , My Code is :

```
  // Get the begin time for the notification by combining the DatePicker
  // value and the TimePicker value.
        DateTime date = (DateTime)FromDatePicker.Value;

        DateTime time = (DateTime)Reminder1.Value;
        DateTime beginTime = date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

But the problem is that i'm getting Error for Typing  .Value  Such as:

Error   1   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePicker' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePicker' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't know How can i substitute this '.Value' to get the exact value for the notification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
DateTime SelectedDate = MyDatePicker.Date.Date;
```

Comment: Thanks ..It  worked for date , But  do you know what can i substitute for TimePicker ?                                                                                          DateTime time = (DateTime)Reminder1.Value;

Comment: Try this : TimeSpan CurrentTime = MyTimePicker.Time;

Comment: It worked but it conflicts with        .TimeOfDay in   this line                                                                                                            DateTime beginTime = date + time.TimeOfDay;

Comment: I think it solved like that ....                                                                     DateTime beginTime = date + date.TimeOfDay;

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected Value from a Datepicker like this:

```
DateTime date = FromDatePicker.Date
```